# Azure Function to use Windows Authentication for On-Premises SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

We already have an express route configured between azure and our local domain. Local AD is also synced with Azure AD. Azure Function is under a VNet which can access on-premises resources.

The problem is when Azure Function tries to access on-premises SQL using Windows Authentication, it gets the error "*Logon Failed*" (which proves that the server is accessible but the user doesn't have permission). Event Log shows **DWASSVC** as the account trying to access DB.

Is there a way we can change the context of Azure Function to run under a specific user which has access to on-Premises SQL DB and any call from Azure Function is generated under that account?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere on this?  I'm looking to do the same thing.  In my case the AZAD and OnPremAD are synced.

Comment: @Aaron No update, we ended up using SQL Authentication. AZAD and OnPremAD are also synced in our case.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Authentication is not possible on Azure App service platform ( Azure web app, Azure Function).

To access on-prem SQL server, you can use Hybrid connection manager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections

Or Put Azure Function in VNET ( ASE) and then make site to site connection.

Comment: We have express route and function is also in VNET, now how to do windows authentication?

Comment: This is the right answer and following this guidance we were able to com from Azure to On Prem.

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT - Is there any update to this answer? We are able to connect to onprem servers using ExpressRoute but not sure how to authenticate with integrated windows auth. Couldn't find any relevant docs.